# Split a list into multiple lists with String and Integers

Tags: scala

I have an input like below:

```
List("aabc", 3, 1, 2, 1, "vwxyz", 2, 3, 4, "sdsafw", 4, 1, 2, 22, 4)
```

And I would like to split it as follows:

```
List(List(“aabc”, 3, 1, 2, 1), List(“vwxyz”, 2, 3, 4), List(“sdsafw”, 4, 1, 2, 22, 4))
```

or

```
List(List(“aabc”, 1, 2, 1), List(“vwxyz”, 3, 4), List(“sdsafw”, 1, 2, 22, 4))
```

(The number right after each “String” actually indicates how many integers come after itself. And if it can be done nicely, I would like to remove it at this point.)

Would you tell me how I can do this?

Comment: It would still be nicer for the reader, and for those who would like to help you, to show your attempts, and the problems you encounter in running your code.
Without it, you probably won't get any help, and rightly so.

Comment: Putting `String`s and `Int`s into the same `List` is _very_ bad practice. I think you need a better data structure, such as `case class Stuff(s: String, xs: List[Int])`. You could then have a `List[Stuff]` no problem.

Comment: @volia17: Thanks for the tip. I’m new to this community, and sill learning the culture. But I’ll keep it in mind and post better next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `List` as

```
val list = List("aabc", 3, 1, 2, 1, "vwxyz", 2, 3, 4, "sdsafw", 4, 1, 2, 22, 4)
```

Then you can write a *recursive function* as

```
def splitList(list: List[Any], tempList: List[Any], listBuffer: ListBuffer[List[Any]]): ListBuffer[List[Any]] = list match {
  case x :: y => if(tempList.isEmpty){
      splitList(y, List(x), listBuffer)
    }
    else {
      splitList(y.drop(x.asInstanceOf[Int]), List.empty, listBuffer += tempList ++ List(x) ++ y.take(x.asInstanceOf[Int]))
    }
  case Nil => listBuffer
}
```

Calling this *function*

```
println(splitList(list, List.empty, ListBuffer.empty[List[Any]]))
```

would give you your desired output

```
ListBuffer(List(aabc, 3, 1, 2, 1), List(vwxyz, 2, 3, 4), List(sdsafw, 4, 1, 2, 22, 4))
```

You can manipulate the desired output with `ListBuffer` or `Array` or `List` according to your need.

Yet Another form of your solution can be using following *recursive function*.

```
def splitList(list: List[Any], tempList: List[Any], listBuffer: ListBuffer[List[Any]]): ListBuffer[List[Any]] = list match {
  case x :: y => if (x.isInstanceOf[String]) {
    if(!tempList.isEmpty){
      splitList(y, List(x), listBuffer += tempList)
    }
    else {
      splitList(y, List(x), listBuffer)
    }
  }else splitList(y, tempList ++ List(x), listBuffer)
  case Nil => listBuffer += tempList
}
```

Comment: It took a while to break down the code, no surprise (sadly) I couldn’t implement it. Thanks for taking your time.

Comment: @hirofujitaaki, what do you mean by couldn't implement it? can you tell me your problem?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Your code completely works. What I was trying to say is “The solution is much more complicated than I expected. No surprise that I couldn’t figure it out myself.”